# Is it possible to input data to a php database on phpmyadmin through a html file or something similar?

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have recently created a form for a website. I need to store the clients data in a database I created through PHPmyAdmin. The form is currently on the website and I'm not sure how to transfer the data from the form to the database.

Any help is massively appreciated.

Comment: you know any php or any other server side language ?

Comment: I am becoming more familiar with php and css for this project although I am probably better at CSS that any others.

Comment: css is not server side language .. please look at PHP form handling, on top of that you at least need to have basic knowledge of sql.

Comment: I realized that as soon as I sent it but yeah PHP is pretty much the only server side language know

Comment: Use PHP to execute your `query` and to post your data etc... I suggest you php.net which is full of nice informations and examples about PHP.
To build up a  connection between your site and your database, you should use mysqli. Even mysqli is described well on php.net (http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) Hope this helps you out <3

Comment: yeah you really need to be familiar with php file handling for this, have a look at [form handling](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp) , else someone is just doing the coding for you .... hope you get that

Comment: I'll have a look at this site thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

- Create a html form
- For the page that it submits to, write code to save it to the database
  Example to save to db:

  ```
  try {
      $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
      // set the PDO error mode to exception
      $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
      $sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
      VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";
      // use exec() because no results are returned
      $conn->exec($sql);
      echo "New record created successfully";
      }
  catch(PDOException $e)
      {
      echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
      }

  $conn = null;
  ?>
  ```

  Check [this site](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp) for more